# Firebase Storage: Limit of concurrent downloads per user session

Tags: firebase-storage

Assuming there are 1000+ thumbnails on Firebase Storage.

The App initializes and downloads these thumbnails.

What is the maximum number of concurrent connections (`Future`s) to download these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many as there is memory to support them.

It's important to know that a Future here is just a way to track the progress of some download.  Maybe what you're really asking about is how many concurrent transfers a single app can have going at the same time. If you're using a Firebase SDK, it internally manages the number of active connections, which is likely going to be limited to 2 or 3 depending on how that SDK was implemented.  All of the downloads will happen over those few connections, no matter how many you have kicked off and have Futures (or promises, or tasks) to represent them.  The SDK will pause the downloads that are waiting for an connection to use, and they will all eventually complete if you have a good network connection.